# Coordinates Conversion from ITM to lat-long i

Tags: sql-server

These are my coordinates:

```
Y                                  X
-------------------------------------    
644796.768174265    199575.078316823

644717.913914994    199367.247692828
646360.979701126    201283.760900855
```

How can I convert it to use them in PowerBI?

Thank you

I tried a lot of formulas but nothing works. Can someone help me please?

I can't use Python, only SQL Server or ADF.

Comment: a quick google search gives me https://zvikabenhaim.appspot.com/software/ITM/ where there are some sql functions at the bottom. I havent' tested them, but they might be enough for you